# LocalAppData folder real and virtualized paths

Tags: desktop-bridge

`LocalAppData` is virtualized for app converted by `Desktop App Converter`.

E.g. "real" `LocalAppData` location is:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local
```

While virtualized `LocalAppData` location is something like:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\MyApp_z4vxg0xscex6e\LocalCache\Local
```

Questions:

1. Is there a way to get the path to virtualized folder from DAC converted app (i.e. second "version")?
2. Is there a way to access non-virtualized `LocalAppData` folder from DAC converted app?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue developing a WPF app installed using MSIX.

I was able to resolve this issue by installing "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" Nuget Package which gave me access to

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder
```

This property provides me with the full non virtualized path.

Useful links:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

[UWP app does not copy file to AppData folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849076/uwp-app-does-not-copy-file-to-appdata-folder)

Answer (score -1):

1) Doesn't using the [known folder IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx) return you with the correct virtualized path?

2) The [following MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/03/06/handling-data-in-a-converted-desktop-app-with-the-desktop-bridge/) has an example of how you can access the non-virtualized folder. Check the article section: **What if I need to deploy some files in the installation folder and some others in the AppData folder?**

Comment: 1) - no, it doesn't.

Comment: 2) - that article is not about accessing NON-virtualized AppData! Did you read my question?